# Encrypting a string

Tags: security, encryption, passwords

Is there a way to encrypt a string so there is no reversable effect? Like if you run some algorith 100 times, encrypting a message, you can run it 100 times in reverse and get the right one. If there a technology or method that eliminates such possibility?

Comment: What you want is a "hash" function - it's a one-way irreversible function. Look into "SHA" - specifically SHA256 seems to be popular now.

Comment: But how is it irreversible?

Comment: It's not actually encrypting the text. It will give you a practically-unique output for a given input (not truly unique, but usually close enough). Basically, given the same input, you hash it twice and get the same output. But given the output, there's "theoretically" no way to get the input. Used a lot in password storage and message integrity checks. Wikipedia it and you'll learn way more than you want to know...

Comment: The term "encrypting" means that there's a way to "decrypt" it. There are lots of different ways to encrypt - symmetric and asymmetric are two of the categories for encryption, and are based on who has access to the encryption keys. But in any of those cases, there's always a way to get the input from the output, assuming you have the appropriate keys. With hashing, you can never ("again, theoretically") find the input given the output.

Comment: If you have something specific in mind, you may want to ask about that, and someone can point you in the right direction as to what technologies to use. For example, if you want to store a password, or if you want to validate a message, or if you want to encrypt a text file on your local machine, or whatever. Whatever you want to do, there are best practices out there for doing it - with cryptography, there's never a single simple answer.

Comment: So what would the term for this? If this is not encrypting? (And I think SHA-256 would be used for me)

Comment: Hashing is the term. @Annabelle's answer explains it very nicely.

Comment: "But how is it irreversible?" Well, SHA1 hashes are 40 characters. That means either data is being lost irretrievably or you can store any amount of data - an entire DVD, for example - in 40 characters.

Comment: From you tags i conclude, that you want to hash passwords. There are algorithms especially designed to hash passwords, they are slow (have a cost parameter) to thwart brute-force attacks. Search for **BCrypt** and **PBKDF2**.

Comment: @ceejayoz SHA-1 has an output of 20 bytes, not 40 characters. That some libraries return the hexadecimal encoding by default is more a nuisance than a benefit.

Comment: @owlstead Be pedantic all you like.

Comment: @ceejayoz my guess is that at least one third of the crypto errors reported here are due to encoding errors, and I certainly did not point this out to bug you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two broad categories you should look into, depending on your needs:

**[Cryptographic Hash Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)**

Cryptographic hash functions produce fixed-width values based on an arbitrarily long input, in such a way that even very minor changes in the input result in significantly different output.   As a rule, they are irreversible (though flaws have been found in some algorithms). This is a good choice if you do not need to be able to recover the value of the string yourself.  For example, good username/password verification systems store a hash of the password rather than the password itself, and authenticate by comparing that hash to the hash of the password provided by the user.  This way, even if the username/password database is compromised, user passwords are not exposed.

**[Public-Key Cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)**

In public-key cryptography, a sender uses the intended recipient's "public" key to encrypt a message, and the recipient uses their "private" key to decrypt it.  The message cannot be decrypted by the same key that encrypted it, so in that sense the algorithm is not strictly "reversible" (splicing hairs, I know).  TLS, SSL, and PGP are all based on this technique, to name a few examples.  This is probably your best option if you are transmitting data between two known parties.

Comment: As a password based key derivation function is the beat method of irreversibly converting a password I'm not sure this answer is sufficient. PKI could be used but it is not an answer by itself.